# MvcSiteMapProvider that supports sub areas

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider

I'm looking for a SiteMap provider for use in an MVC 5 application that can support sub areas.

The folder structure in my project notionally looks something like:

- Project Root

  - Areas

    - Area A

      - Controllers
      - Models
      - Views
      - Areas

        - Area A1

          - Controllers
          - Models
          - Views

I need an MVC SiteMapProvider that allows me to use controllers located in the A1 directory.

I've played with the MvcSiteMapProvider (https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider), and it does not seem to support sub areas in the sitemap file. Is anyone aware of a solution for creating breadcrumbs with this type of setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MVC doesn't support sub-areas without advanced customization, MvcSiteMapProvider does not support them either.

However, there is a project called [MvcCodeRouting](http://mvccoderouting.codeplex.com/) that supports multiple levels of controllers as an *alternative* to MVC areas, and MvcSiteMapProvider has support for it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a good enough answer for the time being:

Using MvcSiteMapProvider, initially I was trying to use the Area, Controller, and Action properties in the mvcSiteMapNode to reach the A1 controller. This was unsuccessful. But if I used the URL property, that worked.

https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-Sitemap-Nodes-in-XML